# Is the "Other Word" VR legal for an 8-bit RGB image?

Tags: dicom

Recently I have seen some color DICOM files with big endian transfer syntax, where pixel data had OW (Other Word) value representation. Byte order in file is

```
R1G1B1R2G2B2 etc
```

AFAIK, according to DICOM standard (part 5, Section 8.1, ***The only difference between OW and OB being that OB, a string of bytes, shall be unaffected by Byte Ordering***), when converting this image to little endian, the byte order should be changed so that it will become

```
G1R1R2B2B2G2 etc
```

but this does not make any sense! This image was obviously intended to have Other Byte value representation. As interesting detail, the image also contained an Icon Image Sequence with a smaller version of pixeldata, that also had OW VR, but here the bytes were actually swapped! (in this manner: G1R1R2B2B2G2). So it's not even consistent...

My question is: is it even legal? And how should I change the endianness of such an image?

**EDIT:** for cdeszaq: acording to DICOM standard part 5, section 7.3:

***VRs that are not a string of characters and consist of multiple bytes are:

    2-byte US, SS, OW and each component of AT

    4-byte OF, UL, SL, and FL

    8 byte FD***

this suggests that the word size is already specified by VR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard also defines how pixels values that use less or more bits than the word they are packed in are aligned in the word, so I think it is legal to have OW as VR (part 5 Annex D)

Comment: There is actually a sample for 8bit image using OW! So it's LE that have the correct order in storage, and that would mean that my sample is wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the endianness of the OW image data, you need to know the size of the words. If you *don't* know the word size, it is impossible to change the endiannes.

To go into a bit more detail, the endianness of a word refers to the ordering of the bytes within the word, either larger-to-smaller, or smaller-to-larger. If you don't know where the word boundaries are in a stream of bytes, it is impossible to re-order them, since you don't know what byte is *currently* in what position within the word.

The lack of words (ie. being nothing more than a stream / string of bytes) is what allows OB objects to be unaffected by the endiannness, since the words are effectively 1 byte long.

Comment: In this case, the BitsAllocated is 8, so one pixel component is 1 byte.

Comment: If the word size is only 1 byte, then the byte ordering doesn't matter, since the ordering of words within the stream must remain the same. As long as the word length is not 3 bytes (ie. the RGB tupple), then the image is simply the wrong object. It should be an OB.

Comment: I've updated the question with some more extracts from dicom standard. Unfortunately, it leaves a lot of space for inconsistensies, and that's my main problem.

Comment: Well, one way to test it, assuming you have something that can read in the image inn question and display it, would be to assume it _does_ use 2-byte words and change it's endianness. If, after conversion, the image displays correctly, it worked. If not, it didn't.

Comment: It's more delicate. Before defining a process that produces good result, it would be good to know it the actual input is legal.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest referencing Annex A of [PS 3.5](ftp://medical.nema.org/medical/dicom/2011/11_05pu.pdf) of the DICOM Standard.
A.2 covers explicit VR little endian and states:

Data Element (7FE0,0010) Pixel Data
- where Bits Allocated (0028,0100) has a value greater than 8 shall have Value
Representation OW and shall be encoded in Little Endian;
- where Bits Allocated (0028,0100) has a value less than or equal to 8 shall have the
Value Representation OB or OW and shall be encoded in Little Endian.

So a VR of OW is acceptable for images with 8 bits allocated (such as RGB where 8 bits are allocated and there are 3 samples per pixel).